# Button click on table view to change the image in my table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have one table view cell with one button. On click of the cell button which has one method to check the if button tag equals to `indexPath.row`. Then I am trying to change the image. But its not showing.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FilterTableViewCell";
    FilterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.cellBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.radioImage.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.cellBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

-(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
     int rowNum = [(UIButton*)sender tag];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_currentSelectedIndex inSection:0];
    FilterTableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (sender.tag == rowNum) {
        cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
    } else {
        cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
    }

}
```

Here button image is not changing. What I need is, when ever I click on any cell that particular cell image needs to change and other cells should show unselected image. And when ever I click on any cell which image is changed as selected image. I needs to get that particular cell values like textlabel name, subtextlabel name.

How can i achive that. What's the problem here ?

Updated :

```
    -(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
    {
       int rowNum = [(UIButton*)sender tag];
FilterTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNum inSection:0]];
 if (sender.tag != _currentSelectedIndex) {
        cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
    } else {
        cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add these two delegates of tableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FilterTableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FilterTableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
}
```

and then change `ButtonClicked` to:

```
-(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    int rowNum = [(UIButton*)sender tag];
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_currentSelectedIndex inSection:0];
    if (sender.tag == rowNum) {
        [_tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }    
}
```

Comment: how can i call the cell .Measn table view cell name in did select row ?

Comment: sorry, I missed that

Comment: does `ButtonClicked` fire by touch ?

Comment: Are you sure about adding images and names ? because this code should work correctly.

Comment: I updated the same code. but still its not chnaging the inage

Comment: `_currentSelectedIndex `  or `rowNum` which one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188536/discussion-between-arash-etemad-and-david).

Comment: hey any help on here plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54839775/bar-chart-not-showing-bars-for-two-values

Answer (score 0):

I read your code. What i found is that you made a mistake in the button tapped method.

```
    -(void)ButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
    {
         int rowNum = [(UIButton*)sender tag];
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_currentSelectedIndex inSection:0];
        FilterTableViewCell *cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (sender.tag == rowNum) {
    cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
        } else {
            cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"];
        }

    }
```

The **if condition** which you have placed is always return true because **first you store the sender's tag to rowNum and then you compare both the two**.

**CONDITION ALWAYS BE TRUE AND FOLLOWING CODE WILL BE EXECUTED**

```
    cell.radioImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"];
```